# Reading stdout from one program in another program

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I have a problem concerning the reading of the stdout in python. I have to explain a bit what I am trying to do.

I have a Python program (*foo*); this calls a second python program (*bar*). *bar* will give back to stdout status details and other information to be logged. The *foo* now has to read this. In principle it works. I can grab the output of *bar* and send it to a log file without any problems. The problems start when I try to look for certain phrases in the output from *bar* (the status report).

I am reading the output with **os.read(fn, n)** from the stdout of *bar*. The problem is that **os.read** reads n bytes, but not a line; it can be more or less. I want it to read every line that is written to stdout by *bar*, these lines end with \n and are written either with **print** or with **sys.stdout.write** followed by a **sys.stdout.flush()**.

*foo* calls *bar* using:

```
bar= subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
fd_in[0] = bar.stdout.fileno()
fd_in[1] = bar.stderr.fileno()
```

My code looks like this at the moment. *bar* writes:

```
print 'TAG INFO1 INFO2 INFO3'
#or
sys.stdout.write('TAG INFO1 INFO2 INFO3\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am reading in *foo* with

```
buf = os.read(fd_in[0], 256)
```

When I write this to a log file with:

```
int_logFile.write(buf)
int_logFile.flush()
```

everything is fine. But if I want to grab the first word of the output line like this:

```
tokens = buf.strip('\n').split(' ')
```

I end up in missery, because I do not get TAG, but I might have INFOx or something from a previous output nothing to do with my status messages.

So to sum it up I need to read the output of *bar* line by line in *foo*. Any ideas???

Comment: Have you tried bar.communicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, `bar.stdout.readline()`? Going all the way to file descriptors is rarely necessary.

Comment: I do not belive this. I was trying all afternoon with `bar.stdout.readlines()` and was getting nowhere. Well good to know it is **That simple** ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about [Popen.communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)? This will also let you send input to the process if you want to.

Comment: Yes, but I want to receive the output from the process, which I also can with communicate, but then I am not quite shure if I will not only get the output when the process has finished, which will not do for my needs. The usage of `readline` does the trick for me at the moment. Thanks for the input though.