# Linux : stdout of one program to stdin of another program

Tags: python, linux, terminal, argparse, pipeline

I checked out [Reading stdout from one program in another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808345/reading-stdout-from-one-program-in-another-program) but did not find the answer I was looking for

I'm new to Linux and i'm using the argparse module in Python to run arguments with a program through the terminal on my Mac

I have program_1.py that inputs a file via sys.stdin and outputs data to sys.stdout

**I'm trying to get program_2.py to take in this data that was outputted to sys.stdout from program_1.py and take it in as it's sys.stdin**

I tried something along the lines of:

```
Mu$ python program-1.py <sample.txt> program-2.py
```

For simplicity, let's say that 'sample.txt' just had the string '1.6180339887'

**How can program_2.py read from sys.stdout of the previous program as it's sys.stdin?**

In this simple example, I am just trying to get program_2.py to output '1.6180339887' to sys.stdout so I can see how this works.

Somebody told me to use the | character for pipelines but I couldn't make it work correctly

Comment: to avoid prefixing `python` each time, you could add at the very top [`#!/usr/bin/env python` line (shebang)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/4279) and set executable permissions for the script: `chmod +x program_1.py`. After that, you could run the script as `./program_1.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a pipe is correct:

```
python program-1.py sample.txt | python program-2.py
```

Here's a complete example:

```
$ cat sample.txt                                                             
hello                                                                        

$ cat program-1.py                                                           
import sys                                                                   
print open(sys.argv[1]).read()                                               

$ cat program-2.py                                                           
import sys                                                                   
print("program-2.py on stdin got: " + sys.stdin.read())                      

$ python program-1.py sample.txt                                             
hello                                                                        

$ python program-1.py sample.txt | python program-2.py                       
program-2.py on stdin got: hello
```

(PS: you could have included a complete test case in your question. That way, people could say what you did wrong instead of writing their own)

Comment: @O.rka I don't know, you don't post any code or error messages

Comment: my error message is : error: unrecognized arguments: sample.txt

Comment: @O.rka, if `<sample.txt` is being correctly processed by the shell, it won't be passed to the program you're invoking at all, so it couldn't possibly be an unrecognized argument. If you showed us *exactly* how you're producing the problem, in enough context that we could reproduce it ourselves...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the error occurs if the incorrect command from the answer is used. OP's question clearly states that program_1.py "inputs a file via sys.stdin" i.e., `<sample.txt` (no error) should be used but the command in the answer uses `program-1.py sample.txt` instead (hence the error).

Comment: @O.rka: you want something like: `<sample.txt python program-1.py | python program-2.py`.

Answer (score 0):

program-1.py:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        sys.stdout.write(f.read())
```

program-2.py:

```
import sys

ret = sys.stdin.readline()
print ret
```

sample.txt

```
1.6180339887
```

in your shell:

```
Mu$ python p1.py txt | python p2.py
```

output:

```
1.6180339887
```

more info here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix) and here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output